# Which android GPUs support "render to float texture"?

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpgpu

I believe that `openGL ES 3.2` (and `3.1` + Android Extensions Pack `AEP`) support it, but I've heard that some GPU's with previous versions (specifically `3.1` without `AEP`) also have this particular extension.

My question is: *how can I tell which GPUs have that particular extension, enabling one to render to a float texture?*

I've searched manufacturer sites, but haven't been able to find this info (maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?)

I'm also a little wary, I heard that one manufacturer added this ability in their driver... but I wonder if that is a software solution (and therefore much slower, defeating the purpose).

Further to this, of course it's possible to do the **encoding decoding in your own shader** - but wouldn't this incur significant overhead? Or, maybe it's fine?

[BTW: the reason I'm asking is I want to purchase a phone to play around with general-purpose computing on mobile GPUs, and the latest phones are much more expensive]

Many thanks for any help! I've been trying to find this on-and-off for months...

Comment: I think it's enough to just check for version of OpenGL. Some of these things are critical parts of OpenGL ES 3, IIRC it's only the pipeline that's different. OpenGL ES itself doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks @Zoe, maybe because I don't understand the `3` innards... but this is for buying a phone, and trying to avoid the expense of a later phone with a `3.2` or `3.1+AEP` GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float rendering support is mandatory in OpenGL ES 3.2. It is *not* required for OpenGL ES 3.0 / 3.1 / 3.1 + AEP.

For earlier implementations you want to use a platform exposing the `EXT_color_buffer_half_float` and/or `EXT_color_buffer_float` extension.

Note that floating point rendering is relatively expensive due to the additional bandwidth, even when supported natively in the hardware. For higher dynamic range consider using something like `RGB10_A2` if you can, it's smaller and faster (and supported in 3.0 core).

Comment: Thanks, that fills in some gaps! Do you know how to find out if a particular GPU supports those 2 extensions? (without actually having the device, and checking for them - because I want to use availability to select a phone to purchase). Also, could you recommend a link/reference for using `RGB10_A2`? I see it's an unsigned integer, and I assume you use it as a fixed-point fraction; but always good to have guidance! I hear what you're saying, `RGB10_A2` may be better if enough dynamic range, because much faster - thanks!

Comment: RGB10_A2 is a unorm format so officially stores a value between 0 and 1 like "normal" color formats, however you can rescale it in your shaders to effectively treat it as arbitrary fixed-point.

Comment: In terms of extension support - I find this site useful http://www.gpuinfo.org/, but YMMV on accuracy.

Comment: http://gpuinfo.org seems great, showing that `adreno 506` (in many cheap midrange snapdragon 625 phones) has both extensions. The `mali-T880` (in popular MT6797/helio x20) also has both. Though, some of the results are inconsistent, claiming `3.2` when those gpus don't have that (as you warned about accuracy). I'm surprised the manufacturers don't simply publish their extensions...?

Comment: A `unorm format` means you write and read from it,mas if it were floating-point (in range [0,1]), except that because only 10 bits per colour, it only stores to a precision of 1/1024?... that seems very convenient. I'm not sure it's enough - I'm wanting to do fluid simulation, with vector fields, and I have no sense of what precision is needed. I had render-to-integer working for other expts, but it didn't work properly for fluid simulation, when I converted to a fraction - but too many other sources of bugs at that time, so I switched to doing fluids on the cpu (still very difficult!!!).

Comment: > "it only stores to a precision of 1/1024" = yes

Comment: Some manufacturers support 3.2, but not the extension for older API versions. Some manufacturers support it in newer driver versions on the same hardware, so older drivers still may not support it even if the hardware could and newer drivers do.

Comment: Hi again, just following up. Table 8.1 of`3.2` spec has 7 renderable float formats, a few are small: `R16F`, `RG16F`,`R32F` and `R11F_G11F_B10F`, but some are 2x32, 3x32, 4x32 bits. The bandwidth concern is just for the larger sizes, isn't it?  I see you're right, AEP does *not* include render-to-float texture (not among the 20 exts in the Pack https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ANDROID/ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a.txt ) And I know from checking before, that they aren't in `3.0` or `3.1`.

Comment: The manufacturer situation is confusing... I think it means that the official capability of a gpu (e.g. as listed on https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Mali_(GPU)#Variants ) might not be available on a particular phone when the phone lacks `3.2` because (a) the exts aren't supported on `3.1` etc (b) the particular version of the driver in the phone doesn't support the exts. So, the only way to tell is from actually checking the phone - and a site like gpuinfo.org gathers such checks. I suppose a phone manufacturer could publish the drivers in their phones and their capabilities, but they just don't...